# Xpath 2.0 - xmlXPathCompOpEval: function matches not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri, mechanize

I am running Xpath 2.0 in my Rails project and tried to use the `matches()` function that it provides like so:

```
page = Mechanize.new.get('http://www.example.com').parser
page.search("//a[matches(text(),'lagerfordon','i')]").first.text
```

which throws the following error:

```
RuntimeError: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function matches not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nokogiri (which Mechanize is built on) uses libxml which supports XPath 1.0, but not XPath 2.0, and so there is no `matches` function available.

You could do a case sensitive match using the [`contains`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function:

```
//a[contains(text(),'lagerfordon')]
```

In order to do a case insensitive match, or to use a more complex regular expression, you will need to filter the result from Mechanize in Ruby, or create a custom XPath function.